# How can I add the contents of a file to the start of another existing file?

Tags: command-line, files

How can I add the contents of a text file to the start of another text file?

There are 3 files named `f1` `f2` `f3`. All of three have some text content.

How can I add the contents of file `f1` at the start of file `f3` and the contents of file `f2` to the end of file `f3`?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `cat` command.  Using your example, `cat f1 f3 f2` will con*cat*enate the files together so that it will read like f1, f3, then f2.  It outputs to `stdout`, so if you want f3 to read like that, you would redirect to a temporary file and then move that file to f3: `cat f1 f3 f2 > tmp ; mv tmp f3`

Comment: thanks chan-ho suh, but i want to make the changes permanently

Comment: Hello.  Sorry about that.  You need to redirect the output of the cat command to a new file and then simply move that file to f3.  Then the change is permanent.  Take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make a temp dir.. touch temp

```
cat f1 >> temp .. temp now has the content of f1
cat f3 >> temp .. temp now has content of f1 and then f3
cat f2 >> temp .. temp now has the content in following order.. f1 f3 f2
mv temp f3 .. now file f3 contains f1 ..f3..f2
```